# Proof Verification: Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Show that the only two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Could someone please verify if my proof of the below exercise is valid? It comes from the 4th edition of Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler - it recently became available and is open access if you are interested.

*Exercise.* Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional. Show that the only two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

> *A subspace $\mathcal{E}$ of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is called a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ if $TE \in \mathcal{E}$ and $ET \in
> \mathcal{E}$ for all $E \in \mathcal{E}$ and all $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.*

> $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the set of linear mappings from a vector space $V$ to $V$.

*Proof.*

**Step 1**

Let's first show that $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Consider first $\{0\}$. It is clearly a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$. Furthermore, the only element in $\{0\}$ is $0$, that is, the zero linear map. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be any mapping. Then $\forall v \in V$,

$$
0T(v)= 0(Tv) = 0 \in \{0\} \implies 0T \in \{0\}
$$

and

$$
T0(v) = T(0v) = T(0) = 0 \in \{0\} \implies T0 \in \{0\}
$$

Since $0T \in \{0\}$ and $T0 \in \{0\}$, it implies $\{0\}$ is a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Now let us consider $\mathcal{L}(V)$. Clearly, $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Let $S, T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ be any two linear mappings. By definition of linear map products (composition), $ST \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $TS \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Thus, $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

**Step 2.**

Now we must show they are the **only** two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Suppose $\mathcal{E}$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $\mathcal{E} \neq \{0\}$ and $\mathcal{E} \neq \mathcal{L}(V)$. This, along with the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional, implies there exists a nonzero linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T \notin \mathcal{E}$ which we are free to define on a basis of $V$, say, the list of vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ such that

$$
T(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) = v_1
$$

Also, let $E \in \mathcal{E}$ such that

$$
E(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) = v_n
$$

I claim that $TE \notin \mathcal{E}$, since if otherwise, that would imply $\forall v \in V$,

\begin{align}
TE(v) = TE(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) &= T(E(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n)) \\ &= T(v_n) \\ &= v_1
\end{align}

showing that both $T(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) = v_1$ and $TE(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) = v_1$, implying that $TE = T$, where $TE \in \mathcal{E}$ implies $T \in \mathcal{E}$, contradicting the assumption that $T \notin \mathcal{E}$. Thus, we must have $TE \notin \mathcal{E}$ which is enough to show that $\mathcal{E}$ cannot be a two-sided ideal of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Thus, $\{0\}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V)$ are the only two-sided ideals of $\mathcal{L}(V)$.

Comment: This is not a "check my proof for me" site. Solution verification posts (which should be so tagged) require that there be a specific step which you are unsure of or unclear about, that the step be explicitly identified, and an explanation for the doubt r confusion be clearly articulated. Otherwise, the post is really multiple questions in one ("is this step right?" so each and every step) and lacking in focus and context, hence unsuitable for the site.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I would say that is your opinion, unless you can point me to the website’s documentation where it says this type of question is unsuitable. 

Also, I would expect someone more well versed than me in linear algebra to be able to look through my proof and pinpoint what is incorrect.

Comment: I direct you to the description of the solution verfication tag, which I already pointed you to: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions."  Which part is unclear to you?  It's not a question of whether one "can", it's whether what you are asking is appropriate for the site

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay, fair enough.